# Query array of JSON objects using Athena | Glue

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, aws-glue, amazon-athena, serde

I have the data in the format of JSON array which looks something like this:

```
[{"name": "abhi", "job": "developer"},{"name": "amal", "job": "captain"},{"name": "nizam", "job": "ca"},{"name": "akshay", "job": "doctor"}]
```

in glue, i created a crawler with custom classifier having jsonpath defined as `$[*]`. After crawling, it successfully identified the column names as

1. name string
2. job string

But when i am trying to query the table using Athena, i am not getting the output in the expected format.

Additional details:

1. The file from which the data is crawled -> is residing in amazon s3.
2. Query used in athena: `SELECT * FROM "<data_source>"."<database_name>"."<table_name>";`
3. IAM role used is having all the necessary permissions
4. Classification -> JSON
5. My data is **NOT** following the format -> single JSON object per line

I was expecting the output to be

| name | job |
| --- | --- |
| abhi | developer |
| amal | captain |
| nizam | ca |
| akshay | doctor |

The output which i received was

| name | job |
| --- | --- |
| {"name": "abhi", "job": "developer"} | {"name": "amal", "job": "captain"} |